# why does functions in Any class in kotlin have no body?

Tags: function, kotlin, any

[image]

I was learning the equals function of the Any class. I looked at the code of the equals function of Any with intellij to know the equals function of the Any class in detail.  However, there was no body of the equals function and The equals function was not even declared as abstract.  But it compiles and I wonder why.  Why?

Comment: It's a special case. The class is not compiled from that code because the compiler treats it uniquely. Same with all the number classes.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. please explain in more detail.

Comment: The compiler does not compile that file as source code. Any is different from any other class. Every other class is a subclass of Any. Any cannot be a subclass of itself so it is completely different from any other class and there is no source code for it that would have syntax that makes sense.

Comment: I see now thank you

Comment: @Tenfour04 java's `Object` have [source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/lang/Object.java), why can't Any?, its not about syntax

Comment: its a `open` fun it can be overridden

Answer (score 3):

<sub>(Copied from [my answer](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/how-exactly-any-is-being-compiled/22686/2) on the Kotlin discussion site.)</sub>

Short answer: it's complicated.

(That's a valid answer to almost any question, of course, but particularly so here!)

Slightly longer answer:

As should be obvious, the [`Any`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/) class isn't compiled from that code.  That just defines how it *appears* to other Kotlin code; it's a sort of stub implementation.

Instead, `Any` is a [mapped type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#mapped-types), which is provided by the relevant platform.  On the JVM, it's mapped to [`java.lang.Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) (which is itself partly implemented by native code, not all written in Java, as you can see from one version of [its source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/lang/Object.java)).

So in the case of the JVM, the actual implementation is effectively split between the stub Kotlin source, parts of the Kotlin compiler, the stub Java source, and parts of the Java runtime.  On other platforms, it'll be different.